# Duplicate Entry in outlook room list

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010

I have created a room list in exchange 2010 and every seems to working fine, except for one small problem. When I drop down the room finder menu, I get the list twice.

I have ensured that the list only has one existence in AD, and I have also rebuilt the address book but it still seems to be showing the list twice.

Comment: Is this just for you, or for everyone? I had this once (just for me) and the only way I could get rid of it was recreate my Outlook profile.

Comment: I believe this is only for me at the moment as I have not enrolled it out to everybody else yet, I will try rebuilding my outlook profile and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Even rebuilding my profile does not work, i used scanpst to fix anything that it could find. i also created a 2nd profile on my laptop and loaded that up and still i get 2 lists. I checked another users settings and they are getting one list like i expected. i imagine its some sort of registry setting and i imagine if i rebuild my laptop it will go away but i dont have the time to do this and its a lot of effort for something that is annoying rather than a blocker. any thoughts?

Comment: Ok i have just figured this out, it was something to do with the registry. Go into the registry, click start type regedit and hit enter.    I then went into HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Office/14.0/Outlook/preferences within here their was a string called RoomFinderRecentRoomList i deleted this entry (i backed up my registry first) i then restarted my outlook and i know only have 1 entry of my "Room List"

Answer (score 4):

Ok i have just figured this out, it was something to do with the registry. Go into the registry,

click start, type regedit and hit enter.

I then went into HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Office/14.0/Outlook/preferences

within here their was a string called RoomFinderRecentRoomList

I deleted this entry (i backed up my registry first)

i then restarted my outlook and i know only have 1 entry of my "Room List"

(Also doing a search within your registry looking for the name of your Room list also works)

Answer (score 0):

So I followed similar steps under the more recent version.

Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Preferences

It does clear the list after the restart, however when booking new rooms it repopulates the data in Outlook as well as the registry.